# HTML Input Value Into Pie Chart Series Data (HighCharts)

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to get values from an html Input and insert those values into JSON series data.

Below is the function that works to load the pie chart with static data but I want to get the values from my html inputs every time the page loads and have those values populate the pie chart.

I'm new to JSON so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
$(function () {

    $('#user_bills_pie').highcharts({

        chart: {

            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '{point.name}',

                }
            }
        },
                    series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Monthly Bills',
            data: [
                ['Cell Phone',   45.0],
                ['Mortgage',       26.8],
                ['Credit Card',    8.5],
                ['Cable/Internet',     6.2],
                ['Electric',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After you created your chart, you will need to get your javascript to do something along the lines of:

```
var chart = $('#user_bills_pie').highcharts();
chart.series[0].addPoint(['Something',15]);
```

Going with the assumption that you will have two text boxes - one for the field name, and the other with the value, you can populate it as such:

```
<input type="text" id="item_name" /> <input type="number" id="item_value" />
<input type="button" value="Clickity Click" id="click_me" />
```

After which you would need to record the Button's click:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint([$("#item_name").val(),parseFloat($("#item_value").val())]);
```

Keep in mind that none of your information is sanitized here, you may want to use something like isNumeric() function that is available in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get vlue by javascript or jquery and paste inside json by variable.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var val1,
        val2,
        options;

    val1 = parseFloat($('input[name=fir]').val());
    val2 = parseFloat($('input[name=sec]').val());

    options = {
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [val1,val2]
        }]
    };

    $('#container').highcharts(options);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JgAPW/